# Jetty Server High CPU Load

Tags: ubuntu, java, cpu-usage, jetty

Sometimes jetty loads our server for 100% - every thread for 100% of 1 core. 
[image]

We have jetty 9 and JDK 1.7 (at Jetty 6 and JDK 1.7 - this doesn't appears).
Jetty now running on default settings, previously we run it with `JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xms4096m -Xmx4096m -server -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC"`
I maked the dump of main thread (with jstack -F pid), but this gives me nothing (i just don't understand). [DUMP](http://pastebin.com/DRWe26ff) 
Is there some way to determine what process/project loading the CPU?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I see in that thread dump is a few threads doing some copying and archiving looks like.  A series of thread dumps taken over a few seconds and minutes would give you an idea of it is those threads behaving badly.  Nothing looks immediately out of place jetty wise in that dump.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was at the one of the project - it makes infinite loop when some specific options accurs.